# MySQL sort query by specific letters

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql table with a lot of folderNames and Directory names, for Example "C:\xx\xyz" or "C:\xx" or "C:\xx\xyz\abc".

Now I have to sort this Query by the count of this Backslashes. I need the Dir C:\xx as first, because I have to create this Directory before I can create a sub-dir in it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT dirName
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY (LENGTH(dirName) - LENGTH(REPLACE(dirName, '\\', '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFillde demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cb5f/1)

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(folder)-LENGTH(REPLACE(folder,'\\',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often not necessary to create directories in order:

```
C:\>mkdir test

C:\>dir test
 El volumen de la unidad C es Sistema
 El número de serie del volumen es: 6882-2759

 Directorio de C:\test

15/02/2013  12:01    <DIR>          .
15/02/2013  12:01    <DIR>          ..
               0 archivos              0 bytes
               2 dirs  115.358.355.456 bytes libres

C:\>mkdir test\foo\bar\one\two\three

C:\>dir test
 El volumen de la unidad C es Sistema
 El número de serie del volumen es: 6882-2759

 Directorio de C:\test

15/02/2013  12:02    <DIR>          .
15/02/2013  12:02    <DIR>          ..
15/02/2013  12:02    <DIR>          foo
               0 archivos              0 bytes
               3 dirs  115.358.355.456 bytes libres

C:\>
```

Comment: Ehm yes, this is possible also, but it does not work for files, I think. I've solved it with the solution above.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue given that the method to create files is normally different from the method to create directories. But of course only you know what your script uses. Glad you got it fixed.